# 3D Vision gaming with NVidia GTX 470 and Epson EH-TW6100

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, projector, 3d-vision

I'm getting really confused about the requirements for 3D vision gaming using NVidia GTX 470 and Epson EH-TW6100. There's some info about this online in various forums, however a lot of it is contradictory and/or 2+ years out of date.

How can I achieve 3D gaming with this equipment? Do I need to buy NVidia 3DTV Play or not? My projector is already 3D capable and comes with its own glasses, so I'm not sure why 3DTV Play is necessary, as all it seems to do is provide an IR transmitter for the NVidia 3D glasses included in the bundle.

If I **do not** require 3DTV Play, then how do I configure my graphics card? There's a wizard for stereoscopic 3D with 4 options: IR Transmitter, Wired Glasses, Pro Hub, Discover glasses. Which should I select and how to proceed?

If I **do** require 3DTV Play, will it be compatible with my EH-TW6100? It is not listed in the compatible projectors on their web site (in fact there are no Epson projectors listed whatsoever), however I read in another forum post that support was added for my projector in a driver update.

Is there a difference in 3D quality between 3D Vision and 3DTV Play, or is the latter purely a hardware add-on for enabling the former?

In all cases, I noticed that it recommends 120Hz to avoid bad lagging. My projector has no drivers and defaults to 60Hz. How can I increase this?

On an aside, my projector is actually the wireless-HD capable version, i.e. EH-TW6100W. Can I use the wireless HDMI transmitter for 3D or should I go direct with HDMI lead?

Comment: Does the `NVidia GTX 470` even have 3D support in the current release of the Nvidia display drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different epson projector (2040) and I have used it for 3d gaming.

I had to:

1. Buy Nvidia 3DTV Play (this enables 3D vision for your projector)
2. Buy glasses (you can probably use the ones you have)
3. Switch to the projector's 3D mode
4. Enable 3D Vision in the Nvidia control panel
5. Go through the calibration / wizard
6. Enable advanced hotkeys (helps you fine tune the 3d settings while gaming)

The 3D sucks in some games, but in some cases you can find some community patches here: http://helixmod.blogspot.com

Have fun!